# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '': id, firstName, lastName, middleName, and 3 more

Tags: reactjs, интерфейс, useeffect

полный код ошибки Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; middleName: string; sectionName: string; email: string; contacts: string; }': id, firstName, lastName, middleName, and 3 more. полная ошибка

пишу код на react вышла ошибка, уже вроде всё, пересмотрел, но не получается разобраться
у меня есть следующий интерфейс

```js
export enum PageMode {
  LOOK = 'look',
  EDIT = 'edit',
}

export interface InitialValue {
  pageForm?: PageMode;
  data: {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    middleName: string;
    sectionName: string;
    email: string;
    contacts: string;
  };
}
```

и такие хуки смотреть на переменную data

```
export const useMentorsCard = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [pageMode, setPageMode] = useState(PageMode.LOOK);
  const mode = searchParams.get('mode');
  let data = {};

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRequest = async () => {
      const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: GET_CURATOR_INFO,
      };

      return axios(config);
    };
    data = getRequest();

    if (mode === 'look') {
      setPageMode(PageMode.LOOK);
    } else if (mode === 'edit') {
      setPageMode(PageMode.EDIT);
    }
  }, [mode]);

  return {pageMode, data};
};
```

сам компонент(в нём и возникает ошибка)

```
export const ModuleMentorsCard = () => {
  const {pageMode, data} = useMentorsCard();

  return <PageForm pageForm={pageMode} data={data} />;
};
```

и такой компонент `PageForm`:

```
export const PageForm = ({pageForm, data}: InitialValue) => {
  switch (pageForm) {
    case PageMode.LOOK:
      return <CardFields data={data} />;
    case PageMode.EDIT:
      return <EditCardFields data={data} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; middleName: string; sectionName: string; email: string; contacts: string; }': id, firstName, lastName, middleName, and 3 more. полная ошибка

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои вопросы: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего вопроса. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: TS ругается, что переменная data может быть {}, что не соответствует объявленному типу. Как вариант, попробуйте в вашем хуке, начальное значение переменной сделать таким же, как описан ваш интерфейс